# Openedge Developer Studio - Cannot install TFS-Plugin

Tags: eclipse, tfs, openedge

Using Openedge 11.7 and trying to install the TFS plugin by Microsoft using the ZIP file from its GitHub but I keep getting this error whenever I try to install it

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.apache.log4j 1.2.15.v201012070815, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.apache.log4j,1.2.15.v201012070815 was not found.
```

I looked up this log4j file and downloaded the version listed and put a PATH to it in my environmental variables yet nothing. I've erased everything to do with the Developer Studio so it installs as clean as possible when reinstalling OE 11.7 yet this error keeps appearing. It used to work fine so I don't know why this is now happening.

Comment: If you install Eclipse 4.5.2, which is what 11.7 PDSOE is based on, can you install the TFS-Plugin?

Comment: Nope still not working

Comment: So you have eliminated Developer Studio being the problem. This is an Eclipse + TFS problem, maybe you will get more relevant help if you add the TFS tag.

Comment: May I ask which TFS plugin it is? Can you please share a link or any document to install this plugin? By the way, what is the TFS version you are using?

Comment: This plugin - https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere
It's worked before with the latest version so I don't know why it's stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, managed to fix it.

Had to extract the plugin contents first and move it all to the plugin folder in Eclipse / Developer Studio. Then I tried to install it like before (Help -> Install new software... etc.) and it installed like it should.
[image: Moving plugin content to eclipse plugin folder]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to install an old version of the TFS plug-in?

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere states:

> Please download this plugin from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) and then install it in Eclipse from where its zip/archive file is saved on disk

Last week's 14.138.0 release contains among others, fixes for log4j:

> log4j 2.,3.2 ([#348](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/348) #351 #354)

The first issue seems similar to your problem.

Comment: I am trying to install the 14.138.0 release, this error occurs when I try installing that version